# Using document.getElementsByName to select multiple options within an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, methods

I have a radio button list with values of 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

I want to accomplish this:

```
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[1]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[2]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[3]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[4]
```

How would this be achieved or is this even possible?

I have tried:

```
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0]&&[1]&&[2]&&[3]&&[4]
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")[0-4]
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish or why, but this is not the way.

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")` returns all matching items, isn't that enough?

Comment: I was simply ignorant of the syntax for it and for some reason I had a hard time finding this specific answer, but that first answer worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just make a loop and access each element.

```
var tax_ret=document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c");
for (var i=0 ; tax_ret.length() ; i++)
   tax_ret[i];
```

but I dont see why you need to do this when this:

```
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c");
```

will get all the elements.

Comment: putting `document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")` inside of the loop is a bad idea. move it outside and store it to a variable. use that inside of the loop.

Comment: One more suggestion use length instead of static 5 value

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use brackets, this will give you the array of elements named "tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c"

```
document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c")
```

as
[Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)
says:

> HTML DOM getElementsByName() Method Gets all elements with the specified name

Comment: Does js have an official manual? is developer.mozilla.org better?

Comment: @SterlingArcher depends on what you use it for, it can be pretty handy at times.

Comment: MDN is a much better resource. being a public wiki anyone can correct mistakes and make additions. w3schools is not open to contributions and has a lot of bad practises. This has been debated to death.

Answer (score 0):

To turn it into a true array, you need to process it a little:

```
var taxReturnArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName("tax_return_cpa_appr_letter_c"));
```

Then you can `forEach()` or `map()` over it:

```
taxReturnArray.map(function(i) {
  // do amazing stuff here
});
```